# advanced regex pattern for html5 input

Tags: regex, html

I can't seem to put together a working pattern to disallow all html tags except for the strong and em tag.

I don't want to parse the html but just want to give the user a warning that the input will not be accepted. I am aware that this is not supported in all browsers but I would love a pure html solution, as I already have a working JS solution, but I wan't to layer the user experience.

```
<input name="user_input" pattern="^(?!<[^>]*>).*$" />
```

So allowed tags: strong, em
the use of all other tags should make the result false

Any one able to crack this one?

KR

**edit:**

```
<input type="text" pattern="((?!<(?!\/?(strong|em))[^>]*>).)*">
```

is what seems to do the trick. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Negative Lookahead `(?!)` for this purpose.

**An example regex string which matches the entire pair:**

`<(?!\/?strong|\/?em)[^>]*>.*(?:<\/.*?>)?`

**A shorter regex, which matches the first tag only**

`<(?!\/?(strong|em))[^>]*>`

---

This match will pass if a HTML tag with something EXCEPT strong or em exists.

So, if match = $true, you can deny the input and give the user a warning.

---

[Regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/rP3jA5)

Comment: Nice! It works like you say it does, almost there now, but I can't control the true/false comparison so everything needs to happen within the pattern. It should give false as soon as a non em or strong tag is found. This should give true:
    My name is <strong>name</strong>.
As for example where
    My name is <strong>name</strong> <span>test</span>.
Should return false

Comment: The problem with matching in that fashion, is that it will match true in this as an example: `<strong>words</strong><span>test</span>` resulting in bad tags being accepted ... I'm assuming that your input will be more than one tag, is that true?

Comment: The matching or order is not important, all input is valid except for html tags other then the strong and em tag. I have been experimenting with your answer to invert the result but I can't get it to work.

Comment: After a good night of rest and your help I have been able to put togheter this:
    <input type="text" pattern="((?!&lt;(?!\/?(strong|em))[^&gt;]*&gt;).)*">
this seems to do what I want, all text is accepted unless an html tag aside 'em' or 'strong' has been used. Thank you very much Vasili!